# How to know why sidekiq job is in dead queue

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

in my system there are dead jobs but our monitoring did not catch any unrescued sidekiq errors. these jobs were scheduled to perform immediately. Is there a way to know why it go to the dead queue? I have run

```
job.error?
job.error_backtrace
```

but the first one returns false and the second one returns nil.

is it possible to know why it moved to dead queue? is it possible there were too many jobs and it waited for a period of time before it give up? thanks

Comment: Have you checked the sidekiq logs?

Comment: What tool do you use for monitoring? Something like eg. Sentry should be able to capture those exeptions. Please check if this tool is configured properly.

Comment: [*The Dead set is a holding pen for jobs which have failed all their retries.*](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#dead-set) Only you can: 1) configure [backtrace handling](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#backtrace-logging) 2) configure [retries](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration) 3) configure exception handling 4) configure [death handling](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#death-notification)